# LoadError for racc/parser.rb - prevents local Jekyll website build

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, github-pages

I am revisiting a static website I built a few years ago with Jekyll, and having trouble compiling the source locally to then send to my github pages website. I am not technically adept so please forgive any mistakes in the below.

The reason for the strange workflow is the need to use Jekyll-scholar and bibtex-ruby gems, so I basically have to build locally, then commit and deploy to github pages. I am seeing the issue below, which stops the jekyll build:

```
C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require': cannot load such file -- racc/parser.rb (LoadError)
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex/name_parser.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bibtex-ruby-6.0.0/lib/bibtex.rb:60:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll/scholar.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-scholar-7.1.3/lib/jekyll-scholar.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from <internal:C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:37:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/3.3.0/bundled_gems.rb:74:in `block (2 levels) in replace_require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:60:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `block in require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:44:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/bundler-2.5.3/lib/bundler.rb:187:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:53:in `require_from_bundler'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/jekyll-4.3.3/exe/jekyll:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby33-x64/bin/jekyll:32:in `<main>'
```

For clarity, I am including the GEMfile:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    addressable (2.8.6)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 6.0)
    bibtex-ruby (6.0.0)
      latex-decode (~> 0.0)
    citeproc (1.0.10)
      namae (~> 1.0)
    citeproc-ruby (1.1.14)
      citeproc (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.9)
      csl (~> 1.6)
    colorator (1.1.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.2.2)
    csl (1.6.0)
      namae (~> 1.0)
      rexml
    csl-styles (1.0.1.11)
      csl (~> 1.0)
    em-websocket (0.5.3)
      eventmachine (>= 0.12.9)
      http_parser.rb (~> 0)
    eventmachine (1.2.7)
    ffi (1.16.3)
    forwardable-extended (2.6.0)
    google-protobuf (3.25.1)
    http_parser.rb (0.8.0)
    i18n (1.14.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    jekyll (4.3.3)
      addressable (~> 2.4)
      colorator (~> 1.0)
      em-websocket (~> 0.5)
      i18n (~> 1.0)
      jekyll-sass-converter (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      jekyll-watch (~> 2.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.3, >= 2.3.1)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.0)
      liquid (~> 4.0)
      mercenary (>= 0.3.6, < 0.5)
      pathutil (~> 0.9)
      rouge (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      safe_yaml (~> 1.0)
      terminal-table (>= 1.8, < 4.0)
      webrick (~> 1.7)
    jekyll-sass-converter (3.0.0)
      sass-embedded (~> 1.54)
    jekyll-scholar (7.1.3)
      bibtex-ruby (~> 6.0)
      citeproc-ruby (~> 1.0)
      csl-styles (~> 1.0)
      jekyll (~> 4.0)
    jekyll-watch (2.2.1)
      listen (~> 3.0)
    json (2.7.1)
    kramdown (2.4.0)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
    latex-decode (0.4.0)
    liquid (4.0.4)
    listen (3.8.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    mercenary (0.4.0)
    namae (1.1.1)
    pathutil (0.16.2)
      forwardable-extended (~> 2.6)
    public_suffix (5.0.4)
    rack (2.2.8)
    rackup (1.0.0)
      rack (< 3)
      webrick
    rb-fsevent (0.11.2)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    rexml (3.2.6)
    rouge (4.2.0)
    safe_yaml (1.0.5)
    sass-embedded (1.69.5-x64-mingw-ucrt)
      google-protobuf (~> 3.23)
    terminal-table (3.0.2)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.1.1, < 3)
    unicode-display_width (2.5.0)
    webrick (1.8.1)

PLATFORMS
  x64-mingw-ucrt

DEPENDENCIES
  jekyll-scholar
  json
  rack (~> 2.0)
  rackup

BUNDLED WITH
   2.5.3
```

As you can see, I am using Ruby 3.3.0 - I'd appreciate any pointers on how to fix this - I see from other forums that there may have been a rights issue with the parser, but I don't know how to fix it, and basically even what I can do (what to comment out, in extremis) - the output format is very unintuitive. Thanks in advance!

I have tried downgrading the versions of relevant gems, and adding new gems suggested by forum posts, all with no luck.

I did not see any relevant posts on jekyllrb talk pages.

Comment: `gem install racc` ?

Answer (score 1):

Add to your `Gemfile` `gem 'racc'` and run `bundle install` in my case it fixed this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having this problem. While the solution posted by Serj works, the ideal fix would be implemented within `bibtex-ruby` itself. I've opened an issue [here](https://github.com/inukshuk/bibtex-ruby/issues/163).